# How do I save user settings to a text file and then have them read and used by the applications settings file

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to get what I put into a text file read by the applications settings located in project properties

So far I have it opening a text file but the settings cannot read from it

```
private void SettingsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start(MyDirectory() + @"\Settings.txt");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what you'd like to achieve. For this purpose, a simple solution is to use your `Settings file` of your project.

[image]

If you use Visual Studio, in Solution Explorer expand your Properties under your project node and you will see Settings.settings file there. If you double click it, you will see a data grid, where you can add properties with type.

[image]

If you've already added some property, you can reference them from your source code like

```
Properties.Settings.Default.MyProperty= "value";
Properties.Settings.Default.IsAdmin = true;
```

It will be stored between your compiled binary file by default, with `<YourAppOutputName>.exe.config`